# Using Libreoffice impress remote app without bluetooth?

Tags: libreoffice

I've just downloaded libreoffice impress remote and got libreO 4.0. My problem is that I can't connect the phone to impress, my laptop doesn't seem to have bluetooth. Anybody know how to solve this? (using ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: may be with wifi. are you sure you don't have bluetooth device in your laptop?

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice Impress head to `Tools` ▸ `Options` ▸ `LibreOffice Impress` ▸ `General` and check ☑ `Enable remote control`. After this you will need to cleanly exit and re-start LibreOffice.

Source: [RemoteHowTo](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Impress/RemoteHowTo)

Comment: Not correct for connecting with WiFi: You will need to go to Tools --> Libreoffice: Advanced --> Enable Experimental Settings --> see https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Impress/RemoteHowTo (bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

The LibreOffice Impress Remote App for [Android devices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.libreoffice.impressremote&hl=en) currently accesses Libre Office Impress from Version 4.0.1.

> There are so many important fixes in this area in 4.0.1, that there is little point playing with 4.0.0.  <sup>[LO Remote Impress HowTo](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Impress/RemoteHowTo)</sup>

The remote controlling of Impress depends on Bluetooth. If your Laptop has no Bluetooth built in you will have to buy an USB Bluetooth Adapter/Bluetooth dongle.

Comment: Does this mean it won't work if Impress is being used from Windows?

Comment: @HammanSamuel: thanks, they apparently included Windows versions now (can't test this).